# How do I install the Gnome Do plugin for Banshee?

Tags: 11.04, banshee, gnome-do

How do I install the Gnome Do plugin for Banshee in Natty? It's not in the plugin list and I have googled half an hour trying to find a way to install it, but most info I found was outdated.

Comment: Try synapse, more lightweight and better than gnome-do

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for certain, but I would try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-do
sudo apt-get install gnome-do-plugins
```

From there, run gnome-do and configure the plugins such that the banshee plugin is enabled.  It had been a while since I have used gnome-do and I would be curious to know how this works for you.

I apologize for not having read your post a bit more closely (it has been a  long day).  I did not read correctly that you are not seeing the Banshee plugin in the Gnome-Do plugin list.